# How should i resize a typed array?

Tags: javascript

So, i have a `Float32Array` with 100 millions of elements. Some of those elements are defected and i need to remove those from the array.

What i did is moved those defected elements at the end. I thought that it would be easy to just resize the array and thus remove the elements from the array. Surprisingly, i could not find a way to do that.

I dont want to create a new array and copy data to that because of memory limitation.

Is there any way what i am trying to achieve? Is there any way to remove those elements from the array without memory duplication?

Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript isn't exactly optimal for such a task, in my opinion, but one thing you could consider is swapping the defective elements to the end of the array (as you said you have already done) and then setting those indices to null. I don't think Javascript provides any efficient ways to resize or remove elements from an array without creating a new copy. However, I could be mistaken, so hence why I am leaving this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Second thought, have you thought about using a Linked List-like setup? That would make removal far simpler, but you would lose some of the convenience methods/properties of an array. However, the ability to remove elements without duplication would be much easier because you can say `previous.next = current.next`, effectively cutting out the node which can then be cleaned up by garbage collection.

Comment: @SpencerD Thats not an option for me, i am actually using three.js and the array i am talking about is the array for vertices, so it has to be typed array. Also, i dont think setting `null` would work either for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `subarray` method returns a new TypedArray based on the same underlying ArrayBuffer so there is no duplication in memory of the original TypedArray's contents.

```js
const a = new Uint8Array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]);

console.log(a);
// Uint8Array [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

const b = a.subarray(2, 4);

console.log(b);
// Uint8Array [30, 40]

console.log(b.byteLength);
// 2
```

Notice that the shared ArrayBuffer itself does not change:

```js
console.log(new Uint8Array(b.buffer));    
// Uint8Array(5) [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 ]

console.log(a.buffer === b.buffer);
// true
```

If the `slice` method was used instead of the `subarray` method above then the memory would be copied, so the buffers would not be equal.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray).

Answer (score 0):

Create the array with the {maxByteLength} options property, then resize it after you have moved thigns to the end.  For example:

```
const array = new ArrayBuffer(1024, { maxByteLength: 2048 });
const data = new Float32Array(array);
// Expect to see 256 here
console.log(data.length); 
for(let i=0;i<data.length; i++) data[i] = i;
array.resize(512);
// Expect to see 128 here
console.log(data.length);
```

Answer (score -3):

When you "remove" items, instead of putting them at the end of the array, use the `slice` method therefore it will be resized dynamically (means that `arr.length` will be updated in the process).

http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/float32array
http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/typedarray/slice

Comment: `array.slice(...)` will return a new copy of the original array, which the OP said he wants to avoid.

Comment: basic(from empty array for instance) `array.slice()` does the same (return new array) but I used it several times and it actually does the modification in the base array. Therefore I guess that if you don't use the return value it's the original array that is takes the return value..

Comment: hmm Interesting observation. I have never looked into that, but I was reading the Mozilla dev pages and it said it returned back a new array. However, if your observations are right, then `array.slice()` would definitely be the way to go.

Comment: I will try that and check if it actually returns a new array or not.

Comment: Apparently, and sadly, it does needa return a new copy of the array :/

Comment: Splice, not slice, shoud be used. Splice mutates the array on which the function is called

Comment: indeed, that's the method I used in the scripts I thought I used slice. Can't help it with those similar names.

Comment: @Vivick Float32Array doesn't have a splice function afaik

Comment: @DouglasGaskell see the links above that show that all typed arrays do in fact have these methods

Comment: @Vivick I think you're confusing `slice()` for `splice()`. The arrays do not actually have a `splice()`, but they do have a `slice()`. The docs you are pointing me to mirror that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array